# PHP Regex String to List

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I got this data from a url using file_get_contents().

```
[
{
    "abbr": "bigrapids",
    "name": "Big Rapids",
    "lat": 43.68757,
    "lon": -85.48229,
    "analytics": "UA-18102548-30"
},
{
    "abbr": "bloomington",
    "name": "Bloomington Transit",
    "lat": 39.1654,
    "lon": -86.52643,
    "analytics": "UA-18102548-24"
},
```

I need to get each of the names (Big Rapids, Bloomington Transit) into an unordered list and then display the list. I've been researching regex fucnctions and I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's JSON, you shouldn't need a regex. Parse it with `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the start of a [JSON string](http://json.org). Assuming that you have the rest of the string, you can parse it using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
$data = '...';
$parsed = json_decode($data);
echo '<pre>', print_r($parsed, true), '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

[live demo](https://eval.in/107919)

you need `decode_json()` for decode json data and then you can have array with subarray then you will have all names.

try like this:

```
$json = <<<JSON
[
{
    "abbr": "bigrapids",
    "name": "Big Rapids",
    "lat": 43.68757,
    "lon": -85.48229,
    "analytics": "UA-18102548-30"
},
{
    "abbr": "bloomington",
    "name": "Bloomington Transit",
    "lat": 39.1654,
    "lon": -86.52643,
    "analytics": "UA-18102548-24"
}]
JSON;

$json_d=json_decode($json,true);
foreach($json_d as $arr){
 echo $arr['name']."  ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$json = <<<EOD
[
{
    "abbr": "bigrapids",
    "name": "Big Rapids",
    "lat": 43.68757,
    "lon": -85.48229,
    "analytics": "UA-18102548-30"
},
{
    "abbr": "bloomington",
    "name": "Bloomington Transit",
    "lat": 39.1654,
    "lon": -86.52643,
    "analytics": "UA-18102548-24"
}]
EOD;

$array = json_decode($json, true); //make sure second parameter is true for a multidimensional array.

echo '<ul>'; // start ul tag
foreach($array as $value){
    echo '<li>' . $value['name'] . '</li>'; // for each value in array make a list item for it
}
echo '</ul>'; // close to ul list tag
```